# jQuery, соединение массива

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

У меня вот такая проблемка, не могу соединить (склеить) элементы массива в одну строку,
вот код:

```
function rt() {
    var first = []; // создаем массив символов
    var stroka = ""; // создаем конечную строку
    $('.sch').append($(this).val()); // после класса выводим на экран по 1 символу
    first[l] = $(this).val(); // заносим каждый символ в массив
    stroka += '' + first[l] + ''; // теперь надо составить одну строку символов
    l++; // увеличиваем индекс массива
    alert(stroka); // выдача для проверки, **выдает только последний символ**
    return stroka; // ну и возврат
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста. :)

Comment: чёт странный код
    
    ['h','e','l','l','o',',',' ','w','o','r','l','d'].join('');

- [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Ну или циклом. join конечно да, короче)

Comment: ну это для моего случая так надо)

Comment: ваш случай в обязательном порядке требует наличия индокода?

Comment: Вы описали задачу совсем не так, как ее "должен выполнять" ваш код.




— Бла-бла-бла, мне нужно выводить в alert'е сумму первой и второй цифры от минут текущий даты, у меня есть код, но он почему-то возвращает неверное значение: alert((minute[1] + minute[2]) / sqrt(hour * rand(1, 5)) + (rand(1, 2) == 1 ? 10 : sqr(rand(10, 50))));

— А зачем в нем деление на час умноженный на рандомное число и еще куча непонятных операций?

— Для моего случая так надо.

Comment: dydydydym что тебе тут не понятно, я даже коменты написал
просто не получается составить строку

Comment: @denisKlimenko, а откуда у вас в функции берется **$(this)**? И, даже если откуда-то берется, то зачем вам еще раз получать строку из массива, если вы её и так получаете отсюда: **$(this).val()**?

Comment: она привязана к клику)
я не хочу весь код выкладывать, просто соедените этот массив $(this) в строку и все)
мне нужна строка)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мде.. Многое для меня останется загадкой, но, хоть я и не телепат, всё же попробую )) Посмотрите [этот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/NbrdJ/2/), может будет полезен.

Answer (score 0):

Вам наверное надо просто инициализировать переменную l. если посмотреть [этот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/chad_888/86hBM/3/),
то видно что без инициализации у вас `l` всегда `NaN` или `undifended` что и приводит к записи в `first[NaN]`.

хотя в Вашем случае есть какое-то расхождение между кодом и вопросом а так же массивом - зачем он вообще нужен. Ваш код аналогичен этому:

```
function rt() {
    var chren = ""+$(this).val()+"";
    $('.sch').append(chren); // добавляем хрень в контейнеры с классом .sch
    alert(chren); // выдача для проверки, **выдает только последний символ**
    return chren; // ну и возврат
}
```

Comment: @denisKlimenko, в рамках вопроса - отредактируйте его чтобы он чётко описывал Вашу задачу и Ваши трудности. Я сомневаюсь что Вы хотите оплатить мне моё время, общаясь не в рамках хешкода :-)

Comment: дядя - Хохол? Оно и видно :-)